# The view main.views.change_password didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I don't know why I ran into this problem. I am using django 2. I am creating a field to change password. Thanks in advance

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST,user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/profile')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

        args={'form':form}
        return render(request,'main/change_password.html',args)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks that if your form is not valid, then that situation doesn't return anything (and thus `None` is returned).

One possible way to fix it is by doing this:

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST,user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/profile')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

    args={'form':form}
    return render(request,'main/change_password.html',args)
```

This way the last two lines will be executed in any situation, and will return correctly. Additionally, the correct `form` will be passed in, and in the case where `form.is_valid()` is `False`, then you'll have access to `form.errors` in the template.

Comment: Thank bro you saved  my time, its 2 am here. Me fixing my bug. Now I can take some sleep.